# Parallel Quicksort with openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, quicksort

I am fairly new to parallel programming. I have the following two implementations of Quicksort with openMP tasks.

1.

```
void quicksort_par(int low, int high, int arr[])
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pivot = partition(low, high, arr);
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp single
            {
                #pragma omp task
                {
                    quicksort_par(low, pivot-1, arr);//Thread 1
                }
                #pragma omp task
                {
                    quicksort_par(pivot+1, high, arr);//Thread2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. 

```
void quicksort(int low, int high, int arr[])
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pivot = partition_r(low, high, arr);
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task
                quicksort(low, pivot-1, arr);
            #pragma omp task
                quicksort(pivot+1, high, arr);
        }
    }
}

void sort(int dim, int arr[])
{
    #pragma omp parallel shared(dim, arr)
    {
        quicksort(0, dim-1, arr);
    }
}
```

While the first one works correctly, the second implementation get stuck in infinite recursion. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: 1. You should control the number of created tasks not to create too many of them. Tasks are expensive and creating as many tasks as items is clearly not reasonable. You need a *cut-off* strategy. 2. Using a `omp parallel` region in tasks recursively is not a good idea as it should cause new threads to be created which is very expensive. Some runtime may actually serialize the execution. Thus please try to avoid nested parallel regions.

Comment: in your second version, you call `quicksort` inside a parallel region. That means that every thread does quicksort on the whole array. You need to put the `omp single` immediately inside the `omp parallel`. Btw, note that your partitioning call is still sequential, so you don't get a lot of speedup in your implementation.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, yes that is correct. But I don't get why it should get stuck in infinite recursion. I tried running with small array dimensions, still the function doesn't end.

Comment: Please post your corrected code.

Comment: The correct working code is the first code block. The faulty one is the second code block posted above.